# The State-Price Deflator in a Binomial pricing model

Tags: option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, binomial

This question comes from a Financial Economics exam and I'm very confused about a state-price deflator which doesn't seem to exist. I've included the whole question for completeness, but my actual question is quite concise.

> An investment bank has issued a two-month European call option on a
>   non-dividend-paying share (whose current price $S_0 = 100$) with a
>   strike price $K = 98$. The risk-free rate of interest $r = 8\%$ per
>   annum and the expected return on the share is $15\%$ per annum, both
>   continously compounded. The share price process is assumed to follow
>   Geometric Brownian motion with the annual standard deviation of the
>   change in the log share price equal to $25\%$.
>
> **tldr**: $S_0 = 100$, $K = 98$, $r = 8\%$, $\sigma = 0.25$ and $dS_t = S_t(0.15dt + 0.25dW_t)$
>
> (i) Construct a two period recombining binomial model where each
>   period is one month, and hence derive the **state price deflators** at
>   time $t = 2$. The parameters determining the share price after an
>   up-jump and down-jump should be those which calibrate the model to the
>   above standard deviation.
>
> (ii) Use the state price deflators from (i) above to derive the value of the option at time $t = 0$.
>
> (iii) Confirm that the same option value is obtained by means of risk-neutral
>   valuation

Now, I can price this option without using state price deflators. A summary of my workings so far is:

Using the Cox-Ross-Rubinstein assumption,, the size of the up-jump:
$$u = e^{\sigma\sqrt{\delta t}} = e^{0.25/\sqrt{12}} = 1.07484 = 1/d$$
Risk-neutral probability of an up-jump: $q = \frac{e^{r\delta t} - d}{u - d} = 0.52826$

From here it is easy to work out the risk-neutral probabilities for each of the states:
$$\mathbb{Q}(\{uu\}) = 0.27907$$
$$\mathbb{Q}(\{ud\}) = \mathbb{Q}(\{du\}) = 0.24920$$
$$\mathbb{Q}(\{dd\}) = 0.22253$$

From there, risk-neutral pricing is easy.

However, what are the **state-price deflators** in this example?

From my notes: the state price deflator in the Binomial model is:

$$A_n = e^{-rn}(\frac{q}{p})^{N_n}(\frac{1-q}{1-p})^{n-N_n}$$

where $N_n$ is the number of upsteps up to time $n$ and $p$ is the real-world probability of an up-step.

However, because we are given that $S_t$ has GBM dynamics in the real-world probability measure:
$$p = \mathbb{P}[\text{up-step}] = \mathbb{P}[S_{t+1} = u \cdot S_t] = 0$$

**My question:** How do we define the state-price deflator when the assumed real-world distribution is continuous but we're working in the (necessarily discrete) Binomial model?

Answer (score 2):

first you have to find the p, u and d that match standard deviations in part (I). The problem is a little underdefined in that even if you match mean and standard deviation precisely, there are multiple solutions. Impose an extra condition to get all three.

Once this is done compute $q$ via 
$$
q = \frac{e^{r \delta t} - d}{u-d}.
$$
The state-price deflator is then found from the ratio $q/p.$

Comment: But what is $p$?

Comment: that is why I said the problem was underdefined. You need to impose an extra condition to make the solution for u d and p unique. eg match 3 moments, take p=0.5, take u = 1/d.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for you to obtain the value for the real world probability measure P, the expected rate of return should be given...else the value of P should be given.

Answer (score 0):

When using, for example, a GBM model, the stochastic process for deflator is:

$$\mathrm{d}Dt = Dt\cdot \left[-r\mathrm{dt}-(\frac{m-r}{s}) \mathrm{d}Zt \right]$$

where $r$ denotes the risk-free rate, $m$ and $s$ are the drift and vol respectively.

If $r$, $m$ or $s$ are time-dependent or even stochastic, use the relevant value for the given projection period or simulation. In a multivariate case, this generalizes to a matrix form, where instead of scalar $m$ you get a vectors of m's, instead of $r$ you get a vector of the same value $r$, and instead of dividing by $s$ you multiply by the cholesky of the inverse covariance matrix.